# Envoy and Evans cli running issue

Tags: protocol-buffers, envoyproxy

I'm writing some envoy control plane based on 
https://github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane

And trying to use `evans cli` for debugging
There is some issue  I can't making it work with envoy data plane.
I've downloaded data-plane 
https://github.com/envoyproxy/data-plane-api

Running evans
`evans -p 5678 envoy/api/v2/*.proto`

`evans: failed to run REPL mode: failed to instantiate a new spec: failed to instantiate the spec from proto files: envoy/api/v2/core/http_uri.proto:11:8: open validate/validate.proto: no such file or dir$
ctory`

Ok install https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate
And run again
`evans -p 5678 --path $GOPATH/src/github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate envoy/api/v2/*.proto`

`evans: failed to run REPL mode: failed to instantiate a new spec: failed to instantiate the spec from proto files: envoy/api/v2/discovery.proto:12:8: open google/rpc/status.proto: no such file or directory`

Is any right way to use data-plane?

And you know correct how-to to generate *.go files with protoc from envoy data-plane *.proto